# what is websocket protocol string?

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket

In my application, a page after being loaded subscribes to stomp over websocket to receive live updates.

The subscription is to a relative path. In chrome devtools, I see the websocket request as going to `wss://<mysite>/<ws-resource>`

However serverside, when I call `request.getScheme()`, it returns `https` and not `wss`.

Comment: Maybe a bug in the frameworks source code? Atleast post some code.

Comment: WSS runs on top on HTTPS, and a WebSocket connection begins life as an HTTP/S connection that is upgraded to WS/S.  Sounds like the framework is not updating the request's `scheme` component after that upgrade is performed.

Comment: can you elaborate on wss runs on top of https? I thought protocol was different. I am talking about the original request, to which the server returns 101